# how to select data from multiple table using multiple dropdown and insert the selected values in one table in database in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Lecture timetable)
{

  Lecture t = new Lecture();
  ViewBag.SId = new SelectList(db.Sections, "Id", "SectionName");
  ViewBag.CId = new SelectList(db.Course, "Id", "CourseName");
  ViewBag.FId = new SelectList(db.Faculty, "Id", "FacultyName");

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {

   db.TimeTable.Add(timetable);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Create");
   }

   return View(timetable);

}
```

Model:

```
[Table("Lecture")]
public class Lecture
{



    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public string Semester { get; set; }


    public int SectionsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SectionsId")]
    public Sections Sections { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public string CreditHourTheory { get; set; }

    public string CreditHourLab { get; set; }

    public int? LabInstructorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LabInstructorId")]
    public Faculty Labinstructor { get; set; }

    public int FacultyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FacultyId")]
    public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoomId")]
    public Rooms Rooms { get; set; }


    public string Day { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TimeStart { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TimeEnd { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "" })
@Html.DropDownList("CId", null , String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control select-section", @required = "" })
@Html.DropDownList("FId", null , String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control select-section", @required = "" })
```

[This is the form with dropdown i want to select these values and after clicking the create button the selected values should be submitted in the table "Lecture" in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLGo7.png)

i am getting some error in inserting the selected value in database. Kindly provide me a better solution for this problem. the values in the dropdown are coming from the database from different tables.

Comment: If you have error, you should add it to the question in full (without missing any text).

Comment: i think you are adding dynamically dropdownlists and want to insert their selected value into DB. if so then you can concatenate the values and save into db by looping one by one comma separated values..

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid column name 'Faculty_Id'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Faculty_Id'.

Source Error:


Line 64:             {
Line 65:                 db.TimeTable.Add(timetable);
Line 66:                 db.SaveChanges();
Line 67:                 return RedirectToAction("Edit");
Line 68:             }   
@OrelEraki

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in your another function **Create** with attribute [HttpGet] (or without any attributes, by default [httpGet]).
Variables in ViewBag must be named as well as members of the class **Lecture** SectionsId, CourseId, FacultyId.

And you should make redirect to **Edit** Action.

So,

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ViewBag.SectionsId = new SelectList(db.Sections, "Id", "SectionName");
  ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Course, "Id", "CourseName");
  ViewBag.FacultyId = new SelectList(db.Faculty, "Id", "FacultyName");

  return View(new Lecture());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Lecture timetable)
{  
  ViewBag.SectionsId = new SelectList(db.Sections, "Id", "SectionName");
  ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Course, "Id", "CourseName");
  ViewBag.FacultyId = new SelectList(db.Faculty, "Id", "FacultyName");

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {    
     db.TimeTable.Add(timetable);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Edit");
   }

   return View(timetable);    
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SectionsId", null, htmlAttributes: new {@id = "SectionsId", @class = "form-control"})
@Html.DropDownList("CourseId", null, htmlAttributes: new {@id = "CourseId", @class = "form-control"})
@Html.DropDownList("FacultyId", null, htmlAttributes: new {@id = "FacultyId", @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Faculty_Id'.

Comment: I think you have a problem in your class Faculty. Please add the code of class Faculty. @Noor